# Hybrid application not showing scroll bar

Tags: java, android, scrollbar, ibm-mobilefirst

My WL6.1.0.1 hybrid application have an overflow (with css set to -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) which scrolls just fine, but I don't see the scroll bar, neither the android feedback when I hit the bottom of the scroll (that glowing light that android have).

Curiously enough if I access the same application via "Common Resources" using the chrome browser on my android device, both the scroll bar and the feedback shows up.

I added the following code to my main java class on the native side (the one that extends WLDroidGap and have the app name)

```
public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath());
    // Add custom initialization code after this line
    this.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
    this.appView.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true);
}
```

But it still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Might be easier to debug with an actual app. Can you create a test case application replicating just this one issue?

Comment: This shows the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lqvS9F1fUSR1YxcUN5VTNOQTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was able to reproduce it here.

Answer (score 0):

For the "feedback", you are probably referring to [EdgeEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html) (when reaching the bottom of the view). If so, it is working for me like this:

```
public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath());
    // Add custom initialization code after this line
    this.appView.setOverScrollMode(appView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
}
```

You can set this in the `onCreate` as well...

For showing the scrollbar, I think you need to use [awakenScrollBars()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#awakenScrollBars(int)) in combination with `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled`.

That said, I don't know the use case of your app, but typically in an app you *would not want* a scrollbar unless specifically in a list or something like that (and maybe not even there...).

Additionally, because you are developing a Hybrid app in Worklight and may target additional environments there are alternative solutions instead of delving into native code, such as using [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) which can take care of much more than just scrolling, but also the "bounce" effect and other things.